# counting related records

Tags: postgresql, computed-column

I have 2 related models, model_A and model_B

There's a 1:n relationship among them

Meaning one record in model_A can have several related records in model_B

I'd like model_A to have a generated (and stored) column

Such generated column should be boolean

It should be set to true if there are 1 or more related records in model_B

It should be false if there are 0 related records in model_B

How do I write the expression to generate such boolean values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a trigger on `model_b` that updates the redundant column in `model_a`.

Don't use `boolean`, because that forces you to count the child rows for each data modification. Not only would that counting be some effort, but it would also introduce a race condition: if two concurrent transactions delete a row, none could see the effects of the other, and you can end up with a wrong result.

Use an `integer` or `bigint` column:

```
CREATE TABLE model_a(
   a_id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
   b_count integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE model_b(
   b_id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
   a_id bigint REFERENCES model_a
);

CREATE FUNCTION laurenz.maintain_count() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' OR TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
      UPDATE model_a
      SET b_count = b_count + 1
      WHERE a_id = NEW.a_id;
   END IF;

   IF TG_OP = 'DELETE' OR TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
      UPDATE model_a
      SET b_count = b_count - 1
      WHERE a_id = OLD.a_id;
   END IF;

   RETURN coalesce(NEW, OLD);
END;$$;

CREATE TRIGGER maintain_count
   AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF a_id OR DELETE ON model_b
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION maintain_count();
```

Demonstration:

```
INSERT INTO model_a (a_id) VALUES (1), (2);
INSERT 0 2

INSERT INTO model_b (b_id, a_id) VALUES (101, 1), (102, 1), (103, 2);
INSERT 0 3

TABLE model_a;

 a_id │ b_count 
══════╪═════════
    1 │       2
    2 │       1
(2 rows)

UPDATE model_b SET a_id = 2 WHERE b_id = 102;
UPDATE 1

TABLE model_a;

 a_id │ b_count 
══════╪═════════
    2 │       2
    1 │       1
(2 rows)

DELETE FROM model_b WHERE b_id = 103;
DELETE 1

TABLE model_a;

 a_id │ b_count 
══════╪═════════
    1 │       1
    2 │       1
(2 rows)
```

Comment: I'm  a bit puzzled - you have `TG_OP = 'UPDATE'` twice - in one case you add to `b_count` and in the other you subract from it - why is this the case?

Comment: @Vérace That is in case somebody updates the foreign key column. See the trigger definition.

Comment: does this apply even if model_A is a view obtained by running a query ?

no insert, update or delete are ever run against this view, as far as I can tell

@LaurenzAlbe

Comment: The trigger has to be on the object that receives the data modification.